# Can't select value of a Dynamically created Combobox at runtime unless using timer

Tags: .net, vb.net, combobox

I create N combobox at runtime and i bind them to different datatables, when i try to select their value at runtime but it's like they haven't loaded any value yet, i can accomplish this task only by using a timer that triggers another event but i can't do this way.
If it can help the combobox are created inside of a custom class panel.

Edit1: Also tryied using a delegate

Works

```
cbodescription.Focus()

        Timer1.Start()

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        For i As Integer = 0 To mLista.Count - 1
            Dim Txtbox As New TextBox
            Txtbox.Tag = i
            Txtbox.Text = mLista(i).Codice.ToString.Trim
            Dim o As New KeyPressEventArgs(Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(Keys.Enter))
            Panel_onTxtCodiceKeyPress(Txtbox, o)
        Next
        Timer1.Stop()
    End Sub
```

Doesn't work

```
cbodescription.Focus()
For i As Integer = 0 To mLista.Count - 1
                Dim Txtbox As New TextBox
                Txtbox.Tag = i
                Txtbox.Text = mLista(i).Codice.ToString.Trim
                Dim o As New KeyPressEventArgs(Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(Keys.Enter))
                Panel_onTxtCodiceKeyPress(Txtbox, o)
            Next
```

KeyPressEvent

```
Private Sub Panel_onTxtCodiceKeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles PanelSF.onTxtCodiceKeyPress
    Dim Tag As Integer = DirectCast(sender, TextBox).Tag
    Dim Value As String = CType(sender, TextBox).Text

    If e.KeyChar = Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(Keys.Enter) Then
        Dim Tipo As Integer = Panel.GetCboType(Tag)

        If ArticoloExist(Tipo, Value) = True Then
            Panel.ChangeDisplayMemberByName(Tag, mItemName)
        End If

        mItemName = ""
    End If
```

ChangeDisplayMemberByName

```
Public Sub ChangeDisplayMemberByName(Tag As Integer, Nome As String)
    Dim Cbo As ComboBox

    For Each Ingrediente As ClassIngredienteRicetta In ListaIngredienti
        If Ingrediente.Numero() = Tag Then
            Ingrediente.Descrizione = Nome
        End If
    Next

    For Each Control As Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf Control Is ComboBox Then
            If Control.Name = "CboArticoli" & Tag Then
                Cbo = Control
                Cbo.SelectedIndex = Cbo.FindString(Nome)
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

any suggestion on how accomplish that task?

Comment: `mLista` or `mListaIngredienti` ?

Comment: mLista it's a list of a class defined by me which each item contains all the information of each Item, mLista.Codice contains Combobox.ValueMember
and mLista.Descrizione contains the Combobox.DislayMember, selecting the value passing the value or searching for the the string returns nothing

Comment: Where have  you placed the code that "doesn't work"?

Comment: I've placed it the Public Sub New()
But i solved thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using a delegate into the Form.Load event